# Java SQLException : Statement already closed

Tags: java, jdbc, atomikos

I am working on a program that allows to compare databases, and I have an issue with the statements.
It has worked perfectly until I decided to use a connection framework that works with Spring (I have to use it for some reasons).

Here is my piece of code (I didn't need to change anything here when I added the connection framework):

```java
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    stmt = connection.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query); // the query is defined above

    // if I replace the 2 lines above by this, it works perfectly
    //rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
    
    pks = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while(rs.next()) {
        pks.add(rs.getString(1));
    }
    
    pks.sort(new KeysNameComparator());
    
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println("Error : " + Utili.getClassName(this) + " : getPrimaryKeys(String) : ");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if ( rs != null ) {
            rs.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if ( stmt != null ) {
            stmt.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, when my program tries to create a statement from a connection, I get this error:

```
14:22:54.154 [main] WARN  c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
14:22:54.154 [main] WARN  c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
14:22:54.154 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: calling createStatement...
14:22:54.191 [main] WARN  c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
14:22:54.191 [main] WARN  c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
14:22:54.191 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: calling createStatement...
14:22:54.206 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.  - Failed to determine if statement was closed - ignoring
java.sql.SQLException: Statement already closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4StatementWrapper.isClosed(JDBC4StatementWrapper.java:75) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractConnectionProxy.purgeClosedStatements(AbstractConnectionProxy.java:43) [transactions-jdbc-4.0.56.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractConnectionProxy.addStatement(AbstractConnectionProxy.java:34) [transactions-jdbc-4.0.56.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.invoke(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:153) [transactions-jdbc-4.0.56.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.createStatement(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at fr.ca.cat.lib.libdephasagescheck.dao.TablesDAO.executeQuery(TablesDAO.java:105) [classes/:na]
    at fr.ca.cat.lib.libdephasagescheck.dao.TablesDAO.getTable(TablesDAO.java:246) [classes/:na]
    at fr.ca.cat.lib.libdephasagescheck.tables.Database.getTablesFromDB(Database.java:77) [classes/:na]
    at fr.ca.cat.lib.libdephasagescheck.compare.DatabaseComparison.compareDatabases(DatabaseComparison.java:64) [classes/:na]
    at fr.ca.cat.lib.libdephasagescheck.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:42) [classes/:na]
```

However, if I just replace:

```java
stmt = connection.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

by:

```java
rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

it works perfectly and I get this in the terminal:

```
14:22:12.808 [main] WARN  c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
14:22:12.808 [main] WARN  c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
14:22:12.808 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: calling createStatement...
14:22:12.840 [main] WARN  c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
14:22:12.840 [main] WARN  c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
14:22:12.840 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@2e385cce: calling createStatement...
```

But I can't use this solution, because this way doesn't allow to close the statement.

When I get the exception, the only difference in the terminal (excluding the exception) is this line:

```
14:22:54.206 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.AbstractConnectionProxy - Failed to determine if statement was closed - ignoring
```

but I don't really know what it means and what to do.

In debug mode, the line that launches the exception is `stmt = connection.createStatement();`, and of course I made sure the connection isn't closed.

I have already read a lot of topics about already closed statement issues, but most of them were solved by not reusing statements in a loop (which can't be applied here).

Would anyone know what happens and what I could do to solve this issue?

**EDIT:**

- It works if I put everything in the try-with-resources (but not if I only add the statement instance), but I would like to understand the "why" because it makes no sense to me.
- The Atomikos version is 4.0.56, but I can't find the mysql one (it's automatically set by another framework I don't have access to).

Comment: First of all, start using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Also try a newer version than your current MySQL Connector/J version (5.1.30 is pretty old), because the stacktrace suggests the problem occurs when Atomikos checks if a statement is closed, and it gets an exception instead of a `true` in response to `Statement.isClosed()`. Which is probably a bug, and I would guess that is solved in more recent 5.1.x (currently: 5.1.49) or 8.0.x (currently: 8.0.27) versions of MySQL Connector/J.

Comment: It works if I put everything in the try-with-resources (but not if I only add the statement instance), but I would like to understand the "why"... The Atomikos version is 4.0.56, but I can't find the mysql one (it's automatically set by another framework I don't have access to). (I've added these information to my post)
But the hypothesis of a bug is really interesting, because before using the connection framework I had added manually the maven mysql dependency. But I'm not sure I can change the version of mysql.

Comment: Your MySQL Connector/J version is listed in the stacktrace (5.1.30), which is a pretty old version. And as I say in my revised comment, this is probably a bug in that MySQL Connector/J version (based on the stacktrace and the expected behaviour of isClosed()).

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'm not sure I can change it, maybe it could work by overriding it in my pom.